# Filing taxes quarterly

Tags: usa, taxes

Do I need to file taxes quarterly if I am self-employed (no matter what), or are there circumstances in which I can file at the end of the year?

For example, if I were employed at another job for which I had taxes withheld, especially if the withheld amount is greater than the owed amount. Is it still required? If so, could I file for both quarterly (and not pay anything) to keep as much in assets as I can?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[According to the IRS](http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Self-Employed-Individuals-Tax-Center), all self-employed persons are **generally required** to file quarterly self-employment and income tax payments that are based off your estimated yearly earnings.  There are exemptions to this rule, as outlined on the IRS page for self-employed individuals, for those that don't make a net profit.

As for working another job where you do pay taxes, if you're still self-employed in another job of your own making then you still need to pay the quarterly self-employment and income taxes.  This is known as having a [part-time business](http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Business-Activities) by the IRS which still falls under the umbrella of being self-employed.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes and I HIGHLY suggest contacting an accountant! It's generally not as expensive as you might think and can save you some headache.

Comment: Hi Drew, we're currently discussing whether or not this site needs the [Back It Up Rule](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181597/question-about-installing-a-compiler-interpreter-for-a-programming-language-of). It's still early, but the better our answers are today, the better the chances will be that this site succeeds! :)

Answer (score -1):

The first year of self-employment, you do not have to file quarterly. After that yes you do.

*Edit* Sorry for not qualifying that. If you don't have any tax liability, there is no need to file the following year.

Comment: During the private beta, try to have longer, more thought out answers. This will help set the mood for the site when it opens up

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. I've never had to file quarterly. According to the 1040 instructions, you only need to file quarterly if you owed taxes the previous year. Otherwise, you won't get penalized. Could you expand this answer out to clarify?

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, could you back this statement up somehow, maybe with a link to a source that discusses it (if providing a link, please also summarise the article content here in case the link gets removed in the future)

Comment: "you only need to file quarterly if you owed taxes the previous year" Oh **!*#^$#**.